# Desactivar checkbox al activar uno de ellos

Tags: javascript, html

tengo distintos checkbox y lo que necesito es que al activar el de `facial completo`, se desactive el cuadrante superior, cuadrante inferior, cuello y papada, y papada. Alguna sugerincia??

```
                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante superior
                    <label for="CuadranteSuperior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteSuperior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Superior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante inferior
                    <label for="CuadranteInferior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteInferior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Inferior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello y papada
                    <label for="CuelloPapada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuelloPapada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello y papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Escote
                    <label for="Escote" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Escote" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Escote">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Facial completo
                    <label for="Facialcompleto" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Facialcompleto" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Facial completo">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Papada
                    <label for="Papada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Papada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello
                    <label for="Cuello" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Cuello" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que llevas intentado? Teniendo un punto de partida siempre es más sencillo ayudarte y así podemos esclarecer tus dudas.

Comment: Hola @phpMyGuel de momento no probe nada por que no se como hacerlo, si con javascript o de algún otro modo

Comment: Interacciones por parte del usuario en entorno Web, siempre Javascript (o a través de su librería JQuery). Te aconsejo que mires el funcionamiento de los eventos `change` que puedes asociar a un `<input>`.

Comment: Los evento change ya los estoy utilizando aquí, ya que muestro un listado de los checks seleccionados y además tengo una imagen de una cara donde según el checkbox seleccionado se me ilumina una parte de la cara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer de manera simple con jquery, con las funciones `change()` y `attr()`, también puedes pasar el valor de `this.checked` para activar y desactivar.

Luego para desmarcar los inputs se puede usar `prop('checked')` y `click()` de modo que se active el evento asociado a estos.

El código queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Facialcompleto').change(function(){
    if($('#CuadranteSuperior').prop('checked'))
      $('#CuadranteSuperior').click();
    $('#CuadranteSuperior').attr('disabled', this.checked);
    if($('#CuadranteInferior').prop('checked'))
      $('#CuadranteInferior').click();
    $('#CuadranteInferior').attr('disabled', this.checked);
    if($('#CuelloPapada').prop('checked'))
      $('#CuelloPapada').click();
    $('#CuelloPapada').attr('disabled', this.checked);
    if($('#Cuello').prop('checked'))
      $('#Cuello').click();
    $('#Cuello').attr('disabled', this.checked);
    if($('#Papada').prop('checked'))
      $('#Papada').click();
    $('#Papada').attr('disabled', this.checked);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante superior
                    <label for="CuadranteSuperior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteSuperior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Superior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuadrante inferior
                    <label for="CuadranteInferior" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuadranteInferior" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuadrante Inferior">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello y papada
                    <label for="CuelloPapada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="CuelloPapada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello y papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Escote
                    <label for="Escote" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Escote" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Escote">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Facial completo
                    <label for="Facialcompleto" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Facialcompleto" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Facial completo">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Papada
                    <label for="Papada" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Papada" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Papada">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>

                  <li class="list-group-item listmodifica">
                    Cuello
                    <label for="Cuello" class="switch2">
                       <input id="Cuello" name="opciones" type="checkbox" class="warning" value="Cuello">
                       <span class="slider5 round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
```

Espero resuelva tu problema, saludos.

Comment: Hola gracias @the-breaker funciona bien, pero al volver a desactivar el facial completo los otros checks no funcionan

Comment: @Miguel ya lo corregí

Comment: Una pregunta, a la ver que de deshabilitan de puede hacer unchecked de los seleccionado que desactivamos??? @the-breaker

Comment: @Miguel claro que se puede, pero no haría falta, cuando se deshabilita un input su valor no se envía al hacer submit, pero puedo agregarlo por si acaso.

Comment: Esque te voy a enseñar algo para que entiendas el porque. Entra aquí por favor http://82.223.25.247:8360/reservar-cita.php una vez aquí elige: HIFU y le das a siguiente, luego FACIAL y le das a siguiente, si te das cuenta los checks son con estilos y al lado derecho tengo un ticket de lo seleccionado @the-breaker

Comment: @Miguel, ya vi la pagina, uff se complica un poco pero ya lo tengo

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda de nuevo, revisa si quieres la pagina, yo seleccione los dos cuadrantes y luego el facial, si que hace el uncheked pero me multiplica los resultados en el tiket

Comment: Y pensandolo bien no tendrian que quedar en disabled, si tienes el facial completo y eliges un cuadrante tendria que suceder a la inversa,  se desactive el facial completo

Comment: @Miguel disculpa, solo puedo responder sobre los limites de la pregunta, para el caso de tu pagina tendrías que preguntar agregando los otros elementos que también son parte del problema.

Comment: Pero el problema de que se multiplican los resultados si los podemos hablar aquí? @the-breaker

Comment: @Miguel, dices del div debajo de Ticket de zonas, eso ya depende de la función con que agregas los li, habría que analizar esa parte del código.

Comment: @Miguel, dices del div debajo de Ticket de zonas, eso ya depende de la función con que agregas los li, habría que analizar esa parte del código.

Comment: Ok! @the-breaker formulare otra pregunta, pero son tantas las dudas que tengo con esto.... muchas gracias por tu ayuda y la solución